# nvmlDeviceGetPowerManagementMode() always returning NVML_ERROR_INVALID_ARGUMENT?

Tags: gpu, nvidia, power-management, kepler, nvml

I am writing a code to measure the power usage of an NVIDIA Tesla K20 GPU (Kepler architecture) periodically using the NVML API.

**Variables**:

```
nvmlReturn_t result;
nvmlEnableState_t pmmode;
nvmlDevice_t nvmlDeviceID;
unsigned int powerInt;
```

**Basic code**:

```
result = nvmlDeviceGetPowerManagementMode(nvmlDeviceID, &pmmode);
if (pmmode == NVML_FEATURE_ENABLED) {
    result = nvmlDeviceGetPowerUsage(nvmlDeviceID, &powerInt);
}
```

My issue is that `nvmlDeviceGetPowerManagementMode` is always returning `NVML_ERROR_INVALID_ARGUMENT`. I checked this.

The NVML API Documentation says that `NVML_ERROR_INVALID_ARGUMENT` is returned when either `nvmlDeviceID` is invalid or `pmmode` is `NULL`.

`nvmlDeviceID` is definitely valid because I am able to query its properties which match with my GPU. But I don't see why I should set the value of `pmmode` to anything, because the documentation says that it is a `Reference in which to return the current power management mode`. For the record, I tried assigning an enable value to it, but the result was still the same.

I am clearly doing something wrong because other users of the system have written their own libraries using this function, and they face no problem. I am unable to contact them. What should I fix to get this function to work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was not directly in the API call - it was in the rest of the code - but the answer might be useful to others. Before attempting this solution, one must know for a fact that Power Management mode is enabled (check with `nvidia-smi -q -d POWER`).

In case of the invalid argument error, it is very likely that the problem lies with the `nvmlDeviceID`. I said I was able to query the device properties and at the time I was sure it was right, but be aware of any API calls that modify the `nvmlDeviceID` value later on.

For example, in this case, the following API call had `some_variable` as an invalid index, so `nvmlDeviceID` became invalid.

```
nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex(some_variable, &nvmlDeviceID);
```

It had to be changed to:

```
nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex(0, &nvmlDeviceID);
```

So the solution is to either remove all API calls that change or invalidate the value of `nvmlDeviceID`, or at least to ensure that any existing API call in the code does not modify the value.